# Need help in alfresco content transformation of avi and wmv to flv

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am transforming avi and wmv to flv format so that I can alfresco preview

Here is the steps I followed

1. Installed ffmpeg 64 bit static build on my windows machine
2. Remove .sample extension of  video-thumbnail-context.xml.sample and video-transformation-context.xml.sample
3. Copied the properties mentioned in the two files to alfresco global properties **(do I need to specify the path of ffmpeg in global properties?)**
4. Created transform and copy rule for a folder and pointed to new folder

But I am getting error when uploading **(Failure: Transformer for 'video/x-ms-wmv' source mime type and 'video/x-msvideo' target mime type was not found. Operation can't be performed)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the following [addon](http://addons.alfresco.com/addons/media-viewers)? Which does basically everything for you.

The code is public via Googlecode (maybe also in the share-extras git).

What I've read is that you need to add the ffmpeg location, like:

```
ffmpeg.exe=C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe
```

Comment: I installed the add on the same error is comin. For here also I need to set the rule right?

Comment: Google a bit mister lazy: http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2012/04/11/share-document-previews-in-alfresco-4/
https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/video-thumbnails-transformation-using-ffmpeg

Comment: I read that before asking the questions the problem was with the rule I created. Thank you

Comment: This will transform the file which is newly added. How to transform the file which is already there?

Comment: I have 25 subfolders each have videos. Is there any rule to apply rule for the entire subfolder because I need to give the destination in rule and the destination cant be same for all subfolders.

Comment: If you setup the rule rightfully for 1 folder, then you can select re-apply rules on sub-folders if that's what you need. If not, then I need more info.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/omRHQli.png please see the image. I need "to" in rule select to (which is the destination folder) if I do this for 1 folder then videos in other folders will be copied to the same folder

Comment: But then you can just use JavaScript. Create action Transform, check at the JavaScript api how to do it. Then you can add the same destination folder as target.